# Determine if value is within range, using modulus

Tags: javascript, modulus

I want to determine if a value is within a range.

All the values are degrees (0 - 359), this causes problems when the `end` value is less than `start` (because of modulo 360).

I need the following statements to return true:

```
isInRange(359 % 360, 359, 2); // Returns false
isInRange(180 % 360, 179, 182); // Returns true
```

---

```
function isInRange(rotation, start, end){
    return (rotation >= start && rotation <= end);
}
```

If necessary it would be possible to determine rotation direction.

Comment: Why should "361°" be between 359° and 2°?

Comment: Sorry i dont know if im just not understanding but `isInRange(361 % 360, 359, 2);` results in `return (1 >= 359 && 1 <= 2);` which correctly resolves to false? How would this return true?

Comment: @Craicerjack Yeah I know, the equation is wrong, that's what I need to fix

Comment: @NickRussler 361° is the same as 1°

Comment: @Drahcir yes, and 1 is not between 2 and 359..?

Comment: @Drahcir ahh, okay.  Thats not clear from the question, and in response to 361 being the same as 1, 1 isnt in the range of 359 and 2

Comment: @NickRussler - Yes I am dumb. Updating question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function isInRange(rotation, start, end){
    return (rotation >= start && rotation <= end) || (rotation >= end && rotation <= start);
}
```

Checks if rotation is in between start and end regardless of which of `start` and `end` is bigger.

Comment: @Drahcir After hours of coding i also often trip over the most simple things :-)